# Google Places Autocomplete Dropdown - how to add custom row in dropdown for no suggestions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-places-api

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var options = {types: ['(cities)'], componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}};
    var input = document.getElementById('searching');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, "place_changed", function() {
        document.getElementById('searching').value = "";
        $('#stat-boxes').hide();
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address;
        var getcityinfo = $.get('/cities', place).done(function(res){
            res = JSON.parse(res);
            var number_sites = (res[0]["count"]);
            var Min_height = (res[0]["min_height"]);
            var Max_height = (res[0]["max_height"]);
            if( number_sites > 0 ){
                $('#num-locations').text(number_sites);
                $('#location-text').text(place);
                if( Min_height && Max_height ){
                    $('#min-max-heights').text(Min_height+"' - "+Max_height+"'");
                } else {
                    $('#min-max-heights').text('Not available');
                }
                $('#stat-boxes').fadeIn();
            } else {
                alert('No results');
            }
```

```html
    <div class="carousel-wrapper">
        <div class="carousel carousel-slider pic-carousel" style="height: 830px;">
            <div class="over-pic carousel-fixed-item center" style="z-index: 1">
                <div class="carousel-control-prev" id="btnPrev"> </div>
                <div class="carousel-control-next" id="btnNext"> </div>
                <input type="text" id="searching">
                <div class="choice-words">
                    <div class="headline">Hello, Welcome to SmallCellSite.com</div>
                    <div class="headline-sub">The largest marketplace for wireless broadband attachments in the US.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item white-text" href="#two!">
                <img src="/img/welcome/scs-home-02.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item white-text" href="#three!">
                <img src="/img/welcome/scs-home-03.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item white-text" href="#four!">
                <img src="/img/welcome/scs-home-04.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item white-text" href="#one!">
                <img src="/img/welcome/scs-home-01.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="stat-boxes" class="stat-boxes-wrapper">
            <div class="stat-box">
                <div class="stat-box-header"><h4>Locations</h4></div>
                <span class="num-locations" id="num-locations">xxx</span>
                <span class="location-text">Assets located in and around</span>
                <span class="location-text" id="location-text">Houston, TX</span>
                <a href="#" class="stat-boxes-link">Municipality Features</a>
            </div>
            <div class="stat-box stat-box-middle">
                <div class="stat-box-header"><h4>Details</h4></div>
                <span class="num-locations" id="min-max-heights">15'-65'</span>
                <span class="location-text">Heights of assets in your search results</span>
                <a href="#" class="stat-boxes-link">Power + Fiber availability</a>
            </div>
            <div class="stat-box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have created a google places autocomplete search box where a user can only search for cities in USA. Everything works fine but now I want to create a new functionality as per following.

Suppose a user types gibberish in the search bar like "ejnfwniefewfneinenfwenefjnew", currently search box stops showing any places for this since no match could be made. But when this happens, I want my dropdown to display only one row displaying message - "No matches found". how can I do that. I read through lot of questions but seems no one has asked for such a feature to be added.

Can someone please explain how to do this and recreate this in code using Javascript and HTMl ?

Comment: JUST ADDED @Siyavash

Comment: @Siyavash Hey, I found a similar answer and its very close to what I wanted to do. Please check the following link: stackoverflow.com/a/10517377/6923941 Run the first answer. I just need one help now - Can you display the custom message ( when no result is returned in pac-container class of google autocomplete) in the dropdown rather than showing in InnerHTML ?